# Multiple Eloquent in laravel with result in one array

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables in db:

shows, episodes, subtitles

shows has:

> *id_show*

episodes has:

> *ep_id, ep_show, ep_episode, ep_season*

subtitles has:

> *sub_id, sub_idshow, sub_episode, sub_season*

Now I have Eloquent for show:

```
 public function episodes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Episodes', 'id_show');
    }
```

When i do:

> $result = Show::find(1)->episodes;

I'm getting all episodes for show, but now I don't know how to add subtitles to these episodes using episode number and season number. Also what is then the best way to result that all. Thanks.

Update:
There is code and it is exactly what I have in my project.

SQL: [SQL info](https://pastebin.com/BG15wuec)

Model show [link](https://pastebin.com/6wuM9vsG)

Model episode [link](https://pastebin.com/Ek97yrzL)

Answer (score 0):

You could create another relationship between episodes and subtitles on your `Episodes` class

```
public function subtitles()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Subtitles', 'ep_id');
}
```

With that you can eager load the episodes and subtitles for each episode

```
$result = Show::with('episodes.subtitles')->find(1)->episodes;
```

This will return the episodes as a collection and you can see the related subtitle on an episode using:

```
$result->get(1)->subtitles;
```

Your code should be something much like this:
    CREATE TABLE `prijevodi` (
        `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `show_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `sezona` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `epizoda` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `deleted` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

```
epizode (episodes)
CREATE TABLE `epizode` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `show_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `sezona` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `epizoda` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `title` text COLLATE utf16_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `airdate` varchar(20) COLLATE utf16_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf16 COLLATE=utf16_unicode_ci;

serije (show)
CREATE TABLE `serije` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `naziv` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `slug` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `img` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'base.jpg',
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `epizode_serije` (\
    `epizode_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `serije_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

class Epizode extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'id_serije', 'sezona', 'epizoda', 'naziv', 'airdate', 'last_tile', 'have_title',
    ];
    protected $hidden = [];
    //protected $appends = ['smf'];

    protected $table = 'epizode';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function prevodi()
    {
        //return $this->hasMany('App\Prevod', 'id_serije');
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Prevod');
    }
}

class Serija extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'naziv', 'slug', 'img', 'opis', 'pregleda', 'kreirao', 'hidden', 'status', 'tema', 'imdb', 'imdb_rating', 'tvdb', 'godina',
        'mreza', 'slovo', 'premijera', 'trajanje', 'drzava', 'jezik', 'zanr', 'cover', 'recommend', 'youtube', 'titleimg',
    ];
    protected $hidden = [];
    protected $table = 'serije';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function epizode()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Epizode', 'id_serije');
    }
}

class Prevod extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'prijevodi';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function epizode()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Epizode');
    }
}
```

Comment: But i don't save ep_id in subtitles, but ep number and ep season. That's how i want to find subitltes by season and episode (and show). Becouse when i delete some episode and add again, then there is no same ID for subtitle and episode.

Comment: That's not an issue. If it's a many to many relationship you can still do the same. Check out the docs on setting up an many-many relationship:
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: I burn up my head xD When i do this, i'm getting syntax error, i use pivot and every example in that manual but can not find solution for show subtitle for episode/season/show. Pfff

Comment: I think I'd need to see more of your code. If you update your question with the new relationship and the structure of your pivot table I'll see if I can spot your problem.

Comment: How can i send you code? And where? Thanks for help :D

Comment: You should be able to update your question and add the new code to it.

Comment: Okay. I think the issue is your `Epizode` model and `prevodi` relationship.
Your SQL tables look okay including the pivot.
I'll update my answer with a suggestion.

Comment: In my previous comment I said your tables look okay. Then I noticed that your pivot table was actually one of your model tables. You need to have a table for each model and an additional table as your pivot.
I've added some code to my answer that should get you on track.

Comment: There is still sql problem. It's getting prevodi_epizode.id but i don't need epizode id. Relationship is "show->episode->subtitle". show have id, episode have id_show, episode number and season of episode. Subtitle have show_id, episode_number, episode_season. Episode is is not using anywhere becouse it's changing when i delete.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your comment. I think you're saying you don't want records in the `Epizode` table to have their own IDs?
You should give them their own IDs that's what eloquent uses to key the relationships.
I don't see any reason why an episode should NOT have an ID. There needs to be some unique identifier for the system to know which episodes to relate to which series and subtitle

Comment: No, i HAVE episode id, but my subtitle is not using that id from episode becouse when i delete episode, id is destroyed and subtitle missing, so i use show_id, and number of episode and season in subtitles base. Episode_id is only for (edit,delete, etc).

Comment: I think you need to rationalise your relationships.
Unless I'm misunderstanding I think you need `shows` that have many `episodes` and `episodes` that have many `subtitles`?
I think a `subtitle` of a given language is unique to a single `episode` so a `subtitle` belongs to one `episode`.
I think an episode belongs to only one show?
Is that a correct summary of the relationships?

Comment: That is correct, but subitle belongs to one episode by number of episode, season of episode and what show. I don't use unique episode id to connect subtitle and episode. That is how i do it.:/ I know it's harder, but that is how it is from begining, i can not channge it now becouse i have so many records. :/